# Enable Touch Events Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, emulation, touch

Google Chrome used to have an option for enabling touch events in the browser. F12->Overrides->Enable Touch Events. With the latest version of Google Chrome for the desktop I can't for the life of me find it. In the Overrides section it just says "Show Emulation View In Console" and checking that doesn't open up any new options either. I tried searching google and all the articles are outdated ones telling me how to do it on versions I already know how to do it on. The Enable Touch Events disappeared just recently, I know last week it was there and I noticed today it no longer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome now has a button that is a picture of a tablet/mobile phone. By clicking this it sets it into mobile emulation which emulates the touch events. There isn't a way to emulate touch events in desktop mode anymore, but touch is effectively for mobile so the mobile emulation is just as effective.

Comment: In my case, I had to still enable Touch Events via the `flags` trick, because with `Fabricjs` it was not firing touch events, even on emulation. Once enabling (forcing) it to to `true` on the `flags` settings, it worked without problems.

Answer (score 8):

Open Google Chrome, go to `chrome://flags` and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to search for "touch" without quotes and make sure `Enable touch events` is set to enabled.

Comment: It was set to automatic. I set it to enabled. Restarted chrome and it still doesn't work. I checked the options available and there isn't any choice for enabling touch events outside of the flags tab.

Comment: This option used to work, but its now gone